# Windows 7 Boot Loader - Remove 30 second waiting time

Tags: windows-7, fedora, grub2

I've installed Fedora 17 and Windows 7 on two different hard disks as a dual-boot system. The default boot loader is GRUB 2 maintained and configured in Fedora 17.

When I startup and choose "Windows 7 bootloader (on /dev/sda1)" in GRUB 2, Windows 7 boot loader will appear, with only Windows 7 as the only choice and also the default operating system, with a 30 second waiting time if no input is detected.

I'm trying to see if it is possible to remove this 30-second waiting time. I've tried to follow the instructions on the Web by configuring default operating system in the control panel but seems there is something wrong with it. I've also tried to use "bcdedit enum /all" but still receives error prompts.

Update: Added my boot tab screen in msconfig.

[image: Startup and Recovery]
[image: BCDEdit, error prompts]
[image: MSConfig Boot Tab]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OR you can use a free GUI tool called as EasyBCD to edit the boot configuration.
Find it here: http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/
Scroll down and get the non-commercial version.

Answer (score 2):

Normally the boot screen of windows with systems to select should not appear when you have only one system setup.
I would definitely take a look at your boot.ini file. It might have an additional line (CRLF) that is causing the screen to show up.

follow these steps:
Start -> Run -> **msconfig**

Go to the Tab [boot.ini].
There you can check if you have one or multiple entries in your file.

This is also the place where you can adjust timeout.

edit:
You can adjust timeout from command line:

```
bcdedit /timeout 1
```

Comment: Seems it is an empty tab as well...updated...

Comment: bcdedit /timeout 1